# Reading evaluated data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a MySQL database-table with the following colums

```
ID
status (can contain values 0, 1, 2)
timepstamp
text
note
owner
```

I'd like to obtain the following information about the entries of aspecific owner from the table:

```
 number of entries
 number of entries where status=0
 number of entries where status=1
 number of entries where status=2
 number of entries where LENGTH(note)>0
 minimum timestamp
 maximum timestamp
```

I used to read the complete datasets and then evaluate them with PHP using

```
SELECT status, timestamp, LENGTH(note)>0 WHERE owner="name";
```

I have the problem that some users have so many entries, that that I frequently get an out of memory error if I read the data to PHP. I thought that letting MySQL evaluating the data should be more performat. I could not manage to write a query that could fulfill this task.

```
SELECT
    MIN(timestamp) AS mintime,
    MAX(timestamp) AS maxtime,
    COUNT(*) AS number,
    ...
WHERE owner="name"
```

Is it somehow possible to obtain the result in one go? For example with a nested WHERE or IFwithin a COUNT?

```
    COUNT(WHERE status=0) AS inactive
    COUNT(IF(status=1)) AS active
    ...
```

How would you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(IF(status=0, 1, 0)) AS stat0,
    SUM(IF(status=1, 1, 0)) AS stat1,
    SUM(IF(status=2, 1, 0)) AS stat2,
    SUM(IF(LENGTH(note)>0, 1, 0)) AS notes,
    MIN(timestamp) AS mintime, 
    MAX(timestamp) AS maxtime
FROM tbl_name
WHERE owner="name"
GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: Works fine. The only think I had to change was the value for the status, since I'm using an ENUM. It seems that MySQL is using the keys for the comparison (and the key for the value "0" is "1",...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
MIN(`timestamp`) AS `mintime`,
MAX(`timestamp`) AS `maxtime`,
COUNT(`ID`) AS `number`,
(SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `Table` WHERE `owner` = 'owner' AND `status` = 0) AS `inactive`,
(SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `Table` WHERE `owner` = 'owner' AND `status` = 1) AS `active`,
(SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `Table` WHERE `owner` = 'owner' AND LENGTH(`note`)>0) AS `longentries`
FROM `Table`
WHERE `owner` = 'name'
```

You should probably consider normalising the database design, though, so that you'll have two separate tables, one for users and one for entries, like this:

USERS
id
name
status

ENTRIES
id
user_id
timestamp
text
note (if this is an entry-specific field; otherwise move it to the table USERS)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your point about normalising the design is valid but using the sub queries to get these stats is very inefficient when it can be done easily without multiple reads.

Comment: I see nothing unnormalized. The `status` can very well be the status of the row, whatevere that stores (text, note) and not the status of the owner.

Comment: Fair points, both - thanks! I didn't even know you could use the syntax you used in your answer, nnichols. Live and learn :) Gave you a +1!